# Linq with multiple Contains/Any

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to construct a LINQ WHERE clause that contains multiple || (or)?

So I have a collection of `EmployeeObject` (List) with each `EmployeeObject` object having a collection of `Department` and I'd like to query this collection of `EmployeeObject` for an `Department`

Here is my code:

```
public static IQueryable<EmployeeObject> QueryableSQL()
{
    IQueryable<EmployeeObject> queryable = EmployeeRepository.GetAllEmployee(); 
    return queryable;
}

public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(Expression<Func<EmployeeObject, bool>> func)
{
   return QueryableSQL().Where(func).ToList();
}
```

EmployeeObject structure:

```
public int Id {get; set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
.....
public IList<Departments> EmployeeDept {get; set;}
```

Department:

```
public int DeptId {get; set;}
public string DeptName {get; set;}
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
string[] array = { "stack", "overflow"};

bool result0 = QLike(t => t.EmployeeDept.Any(x => array.Contains(x.DeptName)));

OR

bool result1 = QLike((t => t.EmployeeDept.Any(x => x.DeptName.IndexOf(array[0], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 || t.EmployeeDept.Any(y => y.DeptName.IndexOf(array[1], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))));

OR

bool result2 = QLike((a => a.EmployeeDept.Any(q => q.DeptName.Contains(array[0])) || a.EmployeeDept.Any(a1 => a1.DeptName.Contains(array[1]))));
```

PS: I have tried different approach but none returns any rows and i do have data in my db.

Comment: Is it a typo that QueryableSQL() doesn't actually return something ?

Comment: it does returns data and once it returns i am adding a where clause to it. as shown in `QLike`

Comment: I'm just saying I don't see a return statement in it. Is that wanted ?

Comment: updated my question i forgot to paste...

Comment: So, you want to return those EmployeeObjects that contain the specified department?  As a suggestion, I would use String.Compare(,,IgnoreCase) == 0 instead of Contain(), and I think that you would only need to pass Func<> not Expression<Func>, but that is just a thought.

Comment: I'm testing a similar scenario in LinqPad, and result0 should work. Make sure your static methods do return values. One other word, result0 doesn't return bool.

Comment: As @mrlucmorin mentioned, it doesn't return bool, will return an enumerable of EmployeeObject(s), I would just use var.

Comment: Are you using EF? Are there EmployeeDept included in your query `.Include("EmployeeDept")` ?

Comment: i am not using EF its sql populating the data in the list

Answer (score 0):

This probably because the Departments is not populated in the original query.

```
public static IList<EmployeeObject> QLike(Expression<Func<EmployeeObject, bool>> func)
{
    var queryable = QueryableSQL().Where(func);
    return queryable.ToList();
}
```

Try to debug queryable variable and you will see how queryable is made of. To make it include Departments you can follow Tony comment Include("EmployeeDept") but it still depends on your ORM framework.

Comment: I mean you put the break-point at queryable.ToList(); and trouble shoot what kind of SQL query the queryable generates. That would reveal a lot of info.